Azure SQL Database :: table size query takes forever to execute
I was working with the awesome Azure SQL Database Diagnostic Information Queries created by Glenn Berry and I realized that the query number 40 takes forever to execute:
-- Get Schema names, Table names, object size, row counts, and compression status for clustered index or heap  (Query 40) (Table Sizes)
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.Schema_ID) AS [Schema Name]
,OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Object Name]
,CAST(SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(19, 2)) AS [Object Size (MB)]
,SUM(p.Rows) AS [Row Count]
,p.data_compression_desc AS [Compression Type]
,'Gives you an idea of table sizes, and possible data compression opportunities' AS Info
FROM sys.objects AS o WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.object_id = ps.object_id
WHERE ps.index_id < 2 -- ignore the partitions from the non-clustered indexes if any
AND p.index_id < 2 -- ignore the partitions from the non-clustered indexes if any
AND o.type_desc = N'USER_TABLE'
--AND p.data_compression_desc = N'NONE'
GROUP BY SCHEMA_NAME(o.Schema_ID)
,p.object_id
,ps.reserved_page_count
,p.data_compression_desc
ORDER BY SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) DESC
,SUM(p.Rows) DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
------
-- Gives you an idea of table sizes, and possible data compression opportunities

This query takes 10 minutes to execute on any database. It doesn't matter if it's a 100Gb database or a 1Tb database.
In the other hand we can have the same result using any of these queries in less than 2 seconds.
So why Glenn's query is so slow?
UPDATE:
If I run this query:
SELECT 
    --t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    --p.rows,
    --SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB
    --SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    --CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    --(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    --CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.

schema_id = s.schema_id
GROUP BY      s.name

I can see the total space taken by each schema.
The Total doesn't sum up with Glenn's query. This because Glenn's query calculates the space based on the sys.dm_db_partition_stats instead of the sys.allocation_units.
And I would like to understand which is the correct way.

It seems a bit silly to ask anyone other than Glenn to troubleshoot the speed of his query.

And you are right @ErikDarling and this is what I'm going to do right now

Have you tried updating system table stats?
